# "Base table or view not found" error in web hosting pdo_mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, case-sensitive, mariadb

I'm 100% done in my project.

I have tested all the pages and links in my **`localhost`**. 100% working.

I then uploaded my project to a free web-hosting site, hostinger.

Anyway, while browsing my project using that server, I encountered ONE ERROR.

It says here in my code:

```
while($numOfRows != 0)
                {
                    $inc++;             

                    $query = "SELECT * FROM ImageTable WHERE ImageId = :id";
                    $query_params = array( 'id' => $inc);        
                    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
                    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
                    $row2 = $stmt->fetch();  
                    if($row2)
                    {
                    $img = $row2['ImageFile'];
                    echo '<img class="foo" id="image" height="300" width="500" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $img ).'"/>';
                    echo '<br>';

                    $query = "select * from events where ImageId = :ImageId";
                    $query_params = array( 'ImageId' => $inc);        
                    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
                    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
                    $row = $stmt->fetch();              
                    echo '<b>Event Name:</b>  '.$row['eventName'].'<br>';                   
                    echo '<b>Description:</b>  '.$row['description'].'<br>';
                    echo '<b>Start Date:</b>  '.$row['startDate'].'<br>';
                    echo '<b>Start Time:</b>  '.$row['startTime'].'<br>';
                    echo '<b>End Time:</b>  '.$row['endTime'].'<br>';
                    echo '<b>Venue:</b>  '.$row['venue'].'<br>';

                    //echo '<a href="delete.php?id='.$inc.'">Delete Event</a>';

                    echo '<br>';
                    echo '<div id="btn2">
                    <a href="participants.php?id='.$inc.'" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">View Participants</a>
                    </div>';
                    echo '<br>';
                    echo '<div id="btn2">
                    <a href="delete.php?id='.$inc.'" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="return checkDelete()" >Delete Event</a>
                    </div>';
                    $numOfRows--;
                    echo '<br><br><br><br><br>';

                    }
```

Even though I remove my **`query_params`**, it returns me the same error.

Take note that it is really my first time to use web hosting sites and to develop a php project.

I browsed the configurations and stuffs of that hostinger and stumbled upon PHP **`Info()`**.

And I checked my localhost WAMPP server PHP `Info()` too.

I compared the **`PDO_MYSQL`** thing.

IN HOSTINGER-site:

```
pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL    enabled
Client API version  10.0.12-MariaDB

Directive   Local Value Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket    /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

IN MY WAMPP SERVER-localhost:

```
pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL    enabled
Client API version  mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: bf9ad53b11c9a57efdb1057292d73b928b8c5c77 $
```

## My question:

**How do I fix the problem?**

Should I change a webhosting site?

Should I change my codes?

Comment: What is error message ?

Comment: it says about PDO and DB MARIA. I have deleted my files already, I'll try to upload it again.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'u239722551_db.ImageTable' doesn't exist' in /home/u239722551/public_html/memberdir/index.php:195 Stack trace: #0 /home/u239722551/public_html/memberdir/index.php(195): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home/u239722551/public_html/memberdir/index.php on line 195

here is the error :(

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the web hosting site is case sensitive when reading your codes!!! I got the error in my query where "ImageTable" can't find by the web hosting site server because I don't have one, but I have imagetable. WAMPP server is not case sensitive, by the way.

Comment: Yes, its not uncommon for MySQL/Maria to be case sensitive on Linux and case insensitive on Windows. This reflects the case sensitivity if the underlying file system.